# For what values of $\alpha$, does this integral converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> For what values of $\alpha>0$ this integral converges
>
> $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}dx $$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you have some $\alpha$ for which you know that the integral converges/diverges? What about $\alpha=0,1,2$?

Comment: It is not possible to answer since you are missing a $d(something)$ in the integral expression.

Comment: Which tools are you allowed to use? The problem may be considerably easier the more advanced tools you are allowed to use.

Comment: Is $x$ measured in degrees or radians? Here that will drastically affect the result.

Comment: @RhysHughes: how so?

Comment: If we can adjust the limit from 1 to $\infty$ then it can  be proven that this integral converges for $\alpha>1$, by integral test, but i am not sure how to show convergence for limit 0 to 1.

Comment: @Fabian see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/johiipjauk for radians, and here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwezw3dx8r for degrees. The graphs are different, so their integral will be too

Comment: @RhysHughes: the value of the integral will be different, but the question whether the integral converges or diverges remains the same...

Comment: @RhysHughes $\sin x$ is *always* in radians, unless indicated otherwise. This is not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral has potential problems at both $x\to 0$ and at $x\to\infty$.

- As the OP correctly points out, the integral over the range $x\in[\epsilon,\infty)$ converges (absolutely) for $\alpha>1$. For $\alpha=1$, it is the well known sine-integral that converges as an improper Riemann integral. For $\alpha <1$ the integral diverges.
- Over the range $x\in [0,\epsilon]$, the integrand is approximately given by
  $$\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha} = x^{1-\alpha } [1 +O(x)]$$
  by Taylor's theorem. In order that the integral converges, we need that $1-\alpha > -1$ or equivalently $\alpha <2 $.

In conclusion, the integral converges for $1\leq \alpha <2$; with absolute convergence except for the value $\alpha=1$.