# Determine convergence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to see for which values of a does the integral

$$
\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\left(1+x\right)^a}
$$

converge.

I know (from this answer: [For what values of $\alpha$, does this integral converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779384/for-what-values-of-alpha-does-this-integral-converge)) that for $$1\le a<2$$ the integral
$$
\int _0^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\left(x\right)^a}$$
converges, but didn't find it very useful...

Answer (score 0):

The function $$\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^\alpha}$$ is well defined at $0$ and its values is $0$. Hence you must check the behaviour at infinity.

Since 
$$\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^\alpha} \sim\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}$$
when $x$ runs to infinity, your case is very similar to the one here: [For what values of $\alpha$, does this integral converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779384/for-what-values-of-alpha-does-this-integral-converge)

Note that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^\alpha}dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^\alpha}dx$$

Take $y=x+1$, then $dx=dy$ and your integral becomes $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^\alpha}$$ which converges if and only if $\alpha >1$.

If $\alpha<1$ then your integral becomes

$$\int_0^\infty (1+x)^{-\alpha}\sin x dx$$ and it clearly diverges. It remains only to deal with the case $\alpha=1$. In such case the integral converges to an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: Why is it clear that for $\alpha<1$ the integral $$\int_0^\infty(1+x)^{-\alpha}\sin{x}\,dx$$ diverges? Further, in the third display the absolute value sign is missing.

Comment: $\sin x \le 1 $ for any $x$.

Comment: From the fact that $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ and the improper interval $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ is convergent it does not follows that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is convergent (even if we assume $g$ to be positive).